# Python variable condition like php

Tags: php, python

I ask if I can to use a variable condition on PYTHON like PHP :

```
<?php $var = (5 = 5) ? true : false; ?>
```

Comment: I hope you mean `$var = (5 == 5) ? true : false;` rather than `$var = (5 = 5) ? true : false;`

Comment: Why would you do that in PHP? Doesn't `$var = true` (or `$var === true` if that's the intent here...) work just as well?

Comment: @Wooble `==` is a comparison operator; `=` is an assignment operator. `5 = 5` should give an error in PHP because you can't assign a value to a value, only to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (also known as the ternary operator) in python, if that's what you mean:

```
me = 5 if a == b else c
```

Comment: It is called the 'conditional expression'. *Ternary* just refers to the number of operators the expression takes, just like `or` is a binary expression operator.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Added just as you commented ;)

Comment: Like [Jon Skeet](https://twitter.com/jonskeet/status/352771042122547200) I also dislike the term 'ternary operator'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Lol :p

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the result of the boolean test in your case:

```
var = 5 == 5  # assigns `True`
```

Otherwise you are looking for a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
var = 'bar' if foo == 5 else 'spam'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean:

```
$var = (5 == 5) ? true : false
```

In Python (2.5 up) this can be written as:

```
b if a else c
```

"First a is evaluated, then either b or c is returned based on the truth value of a; if a evaluates to true b is returned, else c is returned."
http://northisup.com/blog/the-ternary-operator-in-python/